# Find mean and variance of Y while knowing the distribution of X and $YIX$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance, means

Assume that X is uniformly distributed on (0, 1) and that the conditional distribution of Y given X = x is a binomial distribution with parameters (n, x). Then we say that Y has a
binomial distribution with fixed size n and random probability parameter.

I have to find EY and Var(Y). I have find a theorem that says that
$EY = E(E(Y|X))$ and
$VY = V(E(Y|X))+E(V(Y|X))$

But if I have to use this theorem I have first to argue that $E|Y|< \infty$. It seems very obviously, but what will an argument for that be?

If we first try to find EY: First we get that $E(E(Y|X))=E(n \cdot x)$. But how to find this. What is the mean of x? And for VY we get:
$VY = V(E(Y|X))+E(V(Y|X))=V(E(n \cdot x))+E(n \cdot x \cdot (1-x))$. But how can I find the mean of these expressions? I hope anyone can help me

Comment: $E(Y\mid X)=nX$, so $E(Y)=nE(X)$. Every information is there in your question.

Comment: Aha makes sense and X has just the mean $\frac{1}{2}(1+0)=\frac{1}{2}$. So $EY=E(Y|X)=n \cdot \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: This exercise is a straightforward application of the theorem you mentioned in your post.

Comment: Yes thank you I was just a bit confuced, but it makes sense now. But what will an argument be for that $||<\infty$?

Comment: Since $Y\geq 0$ we have $|Y| = Y$, so $E|Y| = EY < \infty$. Alternatively you can simply argue that $Y\leq n$, so $Y$ is bounded.